# How to get Python multiprocessing pool working to write into the same log file

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, logging, multiprocessing

I'm trying to write log into the same log file while running Python multiprocessing pool. But I found my main method didn't work. Can anyone hep to check my code? Thanks.

The below main method verify_html_file_content isn't executed in multiprocessing pool. I'm trying to write logs into the same log file, and the log file is a parameter passing to main method verify_html_file_content:

```
import codecs
import datetime
import os

import multiprocessing

import requests
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

css_xpath = "//link"
js_xpath = "//script"
img_xpath = "//img"
i = 1


def is_404_error(html_url, attr_url, file_path, log_file):
    try:
        r = requests.head(attr_url, headers={'Connection': 'close'})
        if r.status_code == 404:
            log_file.write(file_path + " : " + html_url + " attr: " + attr_url + " return 404!\n")
            log_file.flush()
        else:
            log_file.write(file_path + " : " + html_url + " attr: " + attr_url + " correct!\n")
            log_file.flush()
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print("ConnectionError: " + attr_url)


def verify_html_file_link(driver, html_url, file_path, log_file):
    driver.get(html_url)
    global i
    print("html_file No.: ", i)
    driver.implicitly_wait(15)
    xpath_list = [css_xpath, js_xpath, img_xpath]
    for xpath in xpath_list:
        try:
            des = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath)

            if des != None:
                for node in des:
                    if node.get_attribute("href") != None:
                        is_404_error(html_url, node.get_attribute("href"), file_path, log_file)
                    else:
                        if node.get_attribute("href") != None:
                            is_404_error(html_url, node.get_attribute("src"), file_path, log_file)

        except Exception:
            print("Something wrong with " + html_url)
            log_file.write("Something wrong with file: " + file_path + " : " + html_url)
        finally:
            i += 1


def verify_html_file_content(url, path, log_file):
    chromedriver = os.environ["chromedriver"]

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
    try:
        verify_html_file_link(driver, url, path, log_file)

    except:
        raise

    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    total_html_files_map = {
        "1": "https://www.agoda.com/zh-cn/country/china.html?cid=-38",
        "2": "https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?aid=397647;label=bai408jc-index-XX-XX-XX-unspec-cn-com-L%3Axu-O%3AwindowsS10-B%3Achrome-N%3AXX-S%3Abo-U%3Ac-H%3As;sid=e066c0dc5a7db02a31ae39a76587ff80;city=-246227&;ilp=1;d_dcp=1",
        "3": "https://secure.booking.com/myreferrals.html?aid=397647;label=bai408jc-index-XX-XX-XX-unspec-cn-com-L%3Axu-O%3AwindowsS10-B%3Achrome-N%3AXX-S%3Abo-U%3Ac-H%3As;sid=e066c0dc5a7db02a31ae39a76587ff80;rafftl=1;source=34;",
        "4": "https://www.booking.com/hotel/jp/oakwood-premier-tokyo.html?aid=397647;label=bai408jc-index-XX-XX-XX-unspec-cn-com-L%3Axu-O%3AwindowsS10-B%3Achrome-N%3AXX-S%3Abo-U%3Ac-H%3As;sid=e066c0dc5a7db02a31ae39a76587ff80;dest_id=-246227;dest_type=city;dist=0;hapos=5;hpos=5;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;srepoch=1513924549;srfid=5eb7da030c321979554842f24c64bf54e3e3fcbfX5;srpvid=90612e624185032f;type=total;ucfs=1&#hotelTmpl",
        "5": "https://www.booking.com/hotel/jp/apa-hotel-shinjuku-gyoenmae.html?aid=397647;label=bai408jc-index-XX-XX-XX-unspec-cn-com-L%3Axu-O%3AwindowsS10-B%3Achrome-N%3AXX-S%3Abo-U%3Ac-H%3As;sid=e066c0dc5a7db02a31ae39a76587ff80;dest_id=-246227;dest_type=city;dist=0;hapos=6;hpos=6;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;srepoch=1513924549;srfid=5eb7da030c321979554842f24c64bf54e3e3fcbfX6;srpvid=90612e624185032f;type=total;ucfs=1&#hotelTmpl",
        "6": "https://www.booking.com/hotel/jp/hotel-unizo-ginza-itchome.html?aid=397647;label=bai408jc-index-XX-XX-XX-unspec-cn-com-L%3Axu-O%3AwindowsS10-B%3Achrome-N%3AXX-S%3Abo-U%3Ac-H%3As;sid=e066c0dc5a7db02a31ae39a76587ff80;dest_id=-246227;dest_type=city;dist=0;hapos=7;hpos=7;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;srepoch=1513924549;srfid=5eb7da030c321979554842f24c64bf54e3e3fcbfX7;srpvid=90612e624185032f;type=total;ucfs=1&#hotelTmpl",
        "7": "https://www.booking.com/hotel/jp/apa-sugamo-ekimae.html?aid=397647;label=bai408jc-index-XX-XX-XX-unspec-cn-com-L%3Axu-O%3AwindowsS10-B%3Achrome-N%3AXX-S%3Abo-U%3Ac-H%3As;sid=e066c0dc5a7db02a31ae39a76587ff80;dest_id=-246227;dest_type=city;dist=0;hapos=8;hpos=8;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;srepoch=1513924549;srfid=5eb7da030c321979554842f24c64bf54e3e3fcbfX8;srpvid=90612e624185032f;type=total;ucfs=1&#hotelTmpl",
    }

    thread_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
    log_file = codecs.open("html_files_verification.log", 'w', 'utf-8')
    try:

        for key in total_html_files_map.keys():
            thread_pool.apply_async(verify_html_file_content, args=(total_html_files_map[key], key, log_file,))
        print('Waiting for all subprocesses done...')
        thread_pool.close()
        thread_pool.join()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        log_file.close()

    end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("Duration: ", time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime((end_time - start_time).total_seconds())))
```

Comment: you should remove code in quesition that not related to log file writing.

Comment: try open log file with mode `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is not a good idea to try and write to the same file at the same time from multiple processes. It might or might not work depending on the OS and implementation details.

In the best case it works. In the worst case you get writes from different processes interleaved in interesting ways.

The way to fix this with the least amount of change to your code is to protect the log file with a `Lock` object. That is, you create a `Lock` object before using `apply_async`, and you pass that lock in the `args` of `apply_async`. In the worker process, you `acquire` the `Lock` before writing to the log file. After writing, flush the log file (using the `reset` method) and `release` the lock. This should ensure that only one process at a time is writing to the log file.

Answer (score 1):

There are recipes for logging into a single file from multiple processes in the official Python doc :

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes

Otherwise you could install and activate a system logging agent in your system and use it from a SysLogHandler.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.SysLogHandler

Answer (score 0):

Another option you may consider is log collection per thread and later append those in a single one. I'm using this approach in my python based UI test framework. I keep all thread events in a list and at the end just dump the log into a file. So basically it is a simple dictionary of lists for the entire execution. Experts say

> Python's built-in structures are inherently thread-safe and a lock will adds almost no overhead, giving you peace of mind.

But even if my runs are spread in 20 threads, I've never had any issues for all those years. Same goes for the performance, I didn't found any significant degradation if those collections are used in the way described.

Comment: While it is true in CPython that a lot of built-in structures are mostly thread-safe, this is a consequence of the use of a Global Interpreter Lock in CPython and the way in which the bytecode VM works. This lock ensures that only one thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode. And the python VM only interrupts threads in between bytcodes. Note however that these are *implementation details* of CPython (and some other implementations). It is *not* a guarantee given by the language specification.